# Is there a way to know and reference an Identity during INSERT?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Id2 int NULL,
    Name varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE B
(
    Id int NULL,
    Name varchar(50)

)

INSERT INTO B (Id, Name)
VALUES
(100, 'val1'),
(200, 'val2'),
(NULL, 'val3'),
(NULL, 'val4')

INSERT INTO A
    (Id2, Name)
SELECT Id, Name FROM B

UPDATE A SET Id2 = Id + 100000 WHERE Id2 IS NULL
```

Is there a way to avoid the UPDATE after the INSERT? That is, is there a way to know what the identity value will be and reference it during the insert?

Comment: How about an "on update" trigger on A that does your math there? No need for a seperate `update` query in that case. the rows will get updated automatically as you insert them.

Comment: What would the performance impacts be for having to execute a trigger for every insert instead of the one update? There very well will be 100s of rows inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this by using `instead of insert` trigger

```
create trigger trg_test on A instead of insert
as begin
  INSERT INTO A (name,id2)
  SELECT INSERTED.name,
  case when INSERTED.id2 is null then 10000 else INSERTED.id2 end 
  as super_id from INSERTED;
end
```

You can as well use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger and `UPDATE` the record like

```
create trigger trg_test on A after insert
as begin
    UPDATE a 
    SET id2 = i.Id + 100000 
    FROM A a
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i 
    ON (i.Id = a.Id)
    WHERE a.id2 is null;
end
```

So every record insert the trigger will fire and update the record. So after your `Insert` query completes the result will be as below. [See more about Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189799%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
1   100     val1
2   200     val2
3   100003  val3
4   100004  val4
```

Another Approach without any trigger in place, using a temporary table as below.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    Id2 int NULL,
    Name varchar(50)

);

insert into #temp1(id2,name)
select id,name from B


UPDATE a 
SET id2 = i.Id + 100000 
FROM A a
INNER JOIN #temp1 i 
ON (i.Id = a.Id)
WHERE a.id2 is null;
```

Comment: I don't see how this can work as it doesn't add Id to the constant. Is Id even available here or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for that. As I asked in an above comment, what would the performance impacts be for having to execute a trigger for every insert instead of the one update?

Comment: @Russ, if you are so concerned about performance then see the alternative approach in my edited answer without any trigger. Using a temp table and single update operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OUTPUT clause to find the identity values that have been added to the table:

```
DECLARE @newkeys TABLE (PrimaryKeyValue int)
INSERT INTO A 
(
Name, Id2
)
OUTPUT INSERTED.IDENTITYCOL INTO @newkeys
SELECT Name, Id FROM B
```

But you would still need to update the table as a second step - the identity values aren't available until the INSERT batch has completed.

Comment: So how would that allow one to properly set the Id2 column on insert?

Comment: I don't think you can I'm afraid - the id's aren't available 'in-flight', only after the insert completes.